# svn propset via command line with UTF-8 characters

Tags: svn, command-line, svn-propset

How can i set svn properties via commandline command like this:
"svn propset testprop  "äüöüöü" test.txt"

without getting this: Σⁿ÷ⁿ÷ⁿ as result of "svn propget testprop test.txt"

The argument --encoding didn't work on propset